# How to properly attach an SVG image to a Bootstrap 4 Carousel with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 4 Carousel, which works great, and I'm trying to add a wave (png) effect to the bottom of it with CSS. It works, but it's unreliable in fitting to the width of the carousel, and from the image you can see it's not taking up the full width. How can I get the wave to reliably fill the width (while being responsive)?

I've learnt some CSS in the course I'm doing, but with this, I'm at the point where I'm just fiddling around with it, as logic is no longer prevailing. I have previously set the width over 100% but it is still unreliable, and even the current height & width is actually a skewed view of the wave before it's been rendered. I've attached a copy .svg below.

The HTML

```
<div id="itCarouselControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner carousel-wave">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="./img/carousel/image001.min.jpg" alt="...">
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#itCarouselControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#itCarouselControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.carousel-wave {
  position: relative;
}
.carousel-wave:before {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';                    
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8%;
  z-index: 99;
  background: url('../img/carousel/carousel-wave-lower.svg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I don't have enough points to post an image, so copy of what it is doing can be found [here](https://sbutler44.site/temp/carousel-wave-not-filling-width-stackoverflow.jpg)

Here's a copy of the [.svg](https://sbutler44.site/temp/carousel-wave-lower.svg)

I'd like the image/wave to fill the width of the parent, and have it work in a responsive design. Or is JavaScript required to resolve the issue?

Or as another approach, is my .svg too large? it's 1920px x 73px. Will making it much smaller and let it stretch help perhaps?

Thanks heaps!

Comment: @MattFryer I have checked the .svg and edited regarding using >100% :)

Comment: @MattFryer I've tried adding the wave to over components in my bootstrap project, with much the same result. The issue has something to do with me not understand pseudo elements correctly, I think.

Comment: It seems like your SVG natively has empty spaces on the left and right margins. You will have to crop them out so that they are flush with the edges of the wave path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the `<path>` element in your SVG is not flush with the left and right edges of the viewbox. This is the reason why you have empty spaces on the left and right of the pseudo-element when you overlay it on its parent element:

[image]

If fixing the SVG is not an issue, then you will need to artificially increase the width of the pseudo element so that the empty left and right edges will be hidden:

```css
.carousel-wave {
  position: relative;
  
  /* Demo styles */
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.carousel-wave::before {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';                    
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 112.3"><path d="M1920 54v58.3H0V57.7c156.2-21.8 482.1-24.9 853-4.5 20.7 1.1 41.3 2.3 61.7 3.6l.1-.3c13.8.9 27.6 1.8 41.6 2.7 25.7 1.6 51.7 3.1 78.1 4.6 84.5 4.7 166.7 8.1 245.1 10.3 266 7.7 488.1 2 608.5-14.9 11.6-1.7 22.3-3.4 31.9-5.2z" fill="#fff"/></svg>');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.carousel-wave--fixed {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-wave--fixed::before {
  width: calc(110%);
  left: -5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-wave">Original</div>

<div class="carousel-wave carousel-wave--fixed">Fixed</div>
```

Comment: what do you recommend that I use to edit my SVGs? I've been using Illustrator, but I have been unable to fill the left and right gaps. :(

Comment: @simonB Can’t you shrink the size of the art board and make the edges of the bag snap to the sides?

Comment: I had done that originally, but now I'm thinking my "fuzziness" (not the right word) setting must be too high. I'm planning on setting absolute values to the artboard and object width (rather than relying on the GUI), this afternoon.